# INFO: 'my_robot' extern controller: Waiting for local or remote connection on port 1234 targeting robot named 'my_robot'

Tags: ros2, webots

I using ROS-Foxy on Ubuntu-20.04 installed using WSL 2. I also have installed R2023b version of webots on windows (the host). I followed the ROS-Foxy instructions to setup webots-ros2. However, when I tried running the example at https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Advanced/Simulators/Webots/Setting-Up-Simulation-Webots-Basic.html I got the bellow errors:

```
WARNING: Parquetry "PBRAppearance" > ImageTexture : Texture image size of 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberbotics/webots/R2022b/projects/appearances/protos/textures/parquetry/chequered_parquetry_base_color.jpg' is not a power of two: rescaling it from -1x-1 to 0x0.
WARNING: Parquetry "PBRAppearance" > ImageTexture : Cannot load texture 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberbotics/webots/R2022b/projects/appearances/protos/textures/parquetry/chequered_parquetry_base_color.jpg': Unsupported image format.
WARNING: Parquetry "PBRAppearance" > ImageTexture : Texture image size of 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberbotics/webots/R2022b/projects/appearances/protos/textures/parquetry/chequered_parquetry_normal.jpg' is not a power of two: rescaling it from -1x-1 to 0x0.
WARNING: Parquetry "PBRAppearance" > ImageTexture : Cannot load texture 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberbotics/webots/R2022b/projects/appearances/protos/textures/parquetry/chequered_parquetry_normal.jpg': Unsupported image format.
WARNING: Parquetry "PBRAppearance" > ImageTexture : Texture image size of 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberbotics/webots/R2022b/projects/appearances/protos/textures/parquetry/chequered_parquetry_occlusion.jpg' is not a power of two: rescaling it from -1x-1 to 0x0.
WARNING: Parquetry "PBRAppearance" > ImageTexture : Cannot load texture 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberbotics/webots/R2022b/projects/appearances/protos/textures/parquetry/chequered_parquetry_occlusion.jpg': Unsupported image format.
INFO: 'my_robot' extern controller: Waiting for local or remote connection on port 1234 targeting robot named 'my_robot'.
INFO: 'my_robot' extern controller: connected.
INFO: 'my_robot' extern controller: disconnected, waiting for new connection.
```

I need help on how to resolve this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your Robot Node and check the field "name".
That name **must match exactly** the name of the robot in your launch file.

For instance. If the name in your robot node is "Zachariah", then your launch file will look like:

```
my_robot_driver = Node(
    package='webots_ros2_driver',
    executable='driver',
    output='screen',
    additional_env={'WEBOTS_CONTROLLER_URL': controller_url_prefix() + 'Zachariah'},
    parameters=[
        {'robot_description': robot_description},
    ]
```